# There is already an object named '#t1' in the database

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2014

I run this (via SSMS) in a database in which I have write access (with tmp schema defined), and it works fine:

```
DECLARE @i INT=1
WHILE @i < 5
BEGIN
    PRINT @i;

    IF OBJECT_ID('tmp.t1') IS NOT NULL 
    BEGIN
        DROP TABLE tmp.t1;
    END
    SELECT TOP 3 * INTO tmp.t1 FROM sys.all_columns ac

    IF OBJECT_ID('tmp.t1') IS NOT NULL 
    BEGIN
        DROP TABLE tmp.t1;
    END
    SELECT TOP 3 * INTO tmp.t1 FROM sys.all_objects ao

    IF OBJECT_ID('tmp.t1') IS NOT NULL 
    BEGIN
        DROP TABLE tmp.t1;
    END
    SELECT TOP 3 * INTO tmp.t1 FROM sys.all_parameters ap

    SET @i+=1
END
```

I run this in a database in which I don't have create table access, and it fails during compilation.

```
DECLARE @i INT=1
WHILE @i < 5
BEGIN
    PRINT @i;

    IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#t1') IS NOT NULL 
    BEGIN
        DROP TABLE #t1;
    END
    SELECT TOP 3 * INTO #t1 FROM sys.all_columns ac

    IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#t1') IS NOT NULL 
    BEGIN
        DROP TABLE #t1;
    END
    SELECT TOP 3 * INTO #t1 FROM sys.all_objects ao

    IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#t1') IS NOT NULL 
    BEGIN
        DROP TABLE #t1;
    END
    SELECT TOP 3 * INTO #t1 FROM sys.all_parameters ap

    SET @i+=1
END
```

I'm clearly dropping the table; if anything I'd expect a runtime error but not a compilation error.

Comment: what's the purpose of your query?

Comment: Aside: Using `top` without a corresponding `order by` clause is not a reliable way to get random data.

Comment: @maSTAShuFu:  I'm comparing different join techniques and gathering performance metrics.  I wanted to run it multiple times and take an average.  I know it's an imprecise way of gathering metrics, but it meets my needs (if it worked).

Comment: @HABO:  It's just example code; feel free to remove the TOP 3 bit.  Apologies for the non-relevant bit of code.

Answer (score 1):

It's a compiler behaviour where it can only accept temp tables over SELECT INTO to be used once.

```
  IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#t1') IS NOT NULL 
          DROP TABLE #t1;

    SELECT TOP 3 * INTO #t1 FROM sys.all_columns ac

    IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#t1') IS NOT NULL 
         DROP TABLE #t1;

    SELECT TOP 3 * INTO #t1 FROM sys.all_objects ao   -- this query prompt the error
```

what you can do is

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#t1') IS NOT NULL 
      DROP TABLE #t1;

SELECT TOP 3 * INTO #t1 FROM sys.all_columns ac

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#t2') IS NOT NULL 
     DROP TABLE #t2;

SELECT TOP 3 * INTO #t2 FROM sys.all_objects ao

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#t3') IS NOT NULL 
     DROP TABLE #t3;

SELECT TOP 3 * INTO #t3 FROM sys.all_parameters ap
```

Comment: Ok, so it's a design bug...it works as designed, it's just a poor design (since it works just fine with non-temp tables).  Out of curiosity, anyone know why it's designed this way?

Comment: It’s how the compiler parse your codes specifically SELECT INTO